# gRPC server (Java) doesn't expose service depending on the order in which it is added

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

I am building a gRPC server that needs to expose several services, as below

```java
Server server = ServerBuilder
        .forPort(8980)
        .addService(new GrpcService1())
        .addService(new GrpcService2())
        .addService(new GrpcService3())
        .addService(ProtoReflectionService.newInstance())
        .build();
```

The problem is that there seems to be a conflict between the first two services (`GrpcService1` and `GrpcService2`). If I add `GrpcService1` first, and `GrpcService2` second, then the second service is not exposed. If I add `GrpcService2` first and `GrpcService1` second, the first service is not exposed. The third service is always exposed.

What I mean with "the service is not exposed" is that when trying to run `grpcurl` on one of the second service's rpcs, I get an error like this:

```bash
$ grpcurl -plaintext \                   
  localhost:8980 \
  specs.grpc_service2.GrpcService2/someRpc
Error invoking method "specs.grpc_service2.GrpcService2/someRpc": target server does not expose service "specs.grpc_service2.GrpcService2"
```

Running a `grpcurl list` command does reveal all services, however.

```bash
$ grpcurl -plaintext localhost:8980 list
grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection
specs.grpc_service3.GrpcService3
specs.grpc_service2.GrpcService2
specs.grpc_service1.GrpcService1
```

When using gRPC UI, I get a similar problem, just that the second service added is not included in the list of available services.

Below are some stubs for the proto definitions of the two conflicting services.

`src/main/proto/grpc_service1/services.proto` (used in `GrpcService1`):

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "com.service.internal_query_api";
option java_outer_classname = "InternalQueryGrpcProto";

package specs.grpc_service1;

service GrpcService1 {
...
```

`src/main/proto/grpc_service2/services.proto` (Used in `GrpcService2`):

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "com.service.matform.api";
option java_outer_classname = "MatformGrpcProto";

package specs.grpc_service2;

service GrpcService2 {
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the cause of the problem: you cannot add 2 gRPC services that are defined in Protobuf files with the same name.

In my case, the 2 conflicting services were both defined in 2 files, both named `services.proto`, despite being in 2 different directories and having different namespaces.

The source of this issue comes from the implementation of the `ProtoReflectionService` class ([ProtoReflectionService.java](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/services/src/main/java/io/grpc/protobuf/services/ProtoReflectionService.java)):

```java
if (!seenFiles.contains(fileDescriptor.getName())) {
  seenFiles.add(fileDescriptor.getName());
  fileDescriptorsToProcess.add(fileDescriptor);
}
```

The solution is therefore to rename one of the two `.proto` files to avoid conflict.

Comment: Good debugging there! I was going to suggest you file that as a bug, but it seems like [you already have](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/9705) :)

Comment: @Thomas thanks! I think it's a bug as well because I don't understand the reasoning behind not allowing two `.proto` files with the same name. It should at least consider the package plus the file name.